# Calculate the degrees of an gap in a circle based on the width of the gap

Tags: javascript, geometry, drawing, trigonometry

I'm having a hard time figuring out the trigonometry for the following; I need to draw the outline of a circle with an opening in it of certain pixels in width. The circle can be of various radius but the opening should always be of the same size. In other words if the radius (r) is known and gap width (w) is known, how do you get the gap angle (a)?

I wish I could append an image but I'm not allowed as I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say "gap width" - are you talking about the chord length?

Comment: Yes, that's probably a better way to describe it; the distance between the start and end point of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
chordLength = 2 * radius * sin(angle/2)
```

Then with some algebra

```
angle = arcsin(chordLength/(2*radius))*2
```

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for your very prompt answer.